# Why do we need enum data type in C despite it uses more memory than implementing it by one variable string or even by #define

Tags: c, types, enums

Why do we need enum data type in C despite it uses more memory than implementing it by one variable string.

For example if we have enum as: `

```
enum month {janueary, february, march, april, may, june, july, august, september, november, december};
enum moth aMonth;
aMonth = "janueary" 
aMonth = "february"
```

This enum allocates 12*4 bytes in memory. If we use one string to hold these 12
elements it will be more efficient because we save more memory. In this case code
will be as:

```
char *aMonth;
aMonth = "janueary" 
aMonth = "february"
and so on.
```

If the enum was for example

```
enum month{januearyyyy,february};
```

i.e string characters allocate more than two integers allocate we can use
`#define` for example:

```
#define janueary 0
```

and so on. without even allocate any variables.

It makes no seance to reserve 4 bytes for only one constant value!

Some books says that idea of enum that you can store in enum's variables only the elements of enum and no other values. But most compilers allow you to use identifiers as normal integer variable and use other values.

So, what's benefits we are getting when using enum data types?

Comment: You can't assign strings to an enum. Your first example makes no sense.

Comment: "This enum allocates 12*4 bytes in memory." - no it doesn't - it's just syntactic sugar for an integer with special values. Can I respectfully suggest getting hold of [a good book on C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/562303/253056) and doing some studying ?

Comment: Declaring an enum type doesn't reserve any memory. Declaring a variable reserves memory, but the same thing happens if you declare an `int` variable and assign it from the macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main purpose that enums serve is that they provide self-documentation of the intent of a variable. When you write:

```
enum month aMonth;
```

it's clear that the values of `aMonth` should only come from the set of constants declared in the enum. If you used macros instead, you would declare it:

```
int aMonth;
```

and there's nothing that tells you which values are appropriate or not.

As you note, C doesn't prevent you from using values outside the enum type when you assign to the variable, but a compiler could still warn about it. Without the type declaration, there would be no way for the compiler to know what to warn about.

Declaring the enum doesn't reserve any memory. Memory is only assigned to variables, not declarations of structs and enums. And the size of an enum is not multiplied by the number of elements -- `sizeof(enum month)` is not `12*4`. The compiler is allowed to use any integer type that's big enough to hold all the values; for `enum month`, it could use `unsigned char`, so it would only be 1 byte (but I think most compilers default to using `int` for enums, so they'll be 4 bytes).

Comment: So, identifiers are constant and don't allocate memory,aren't they?
But if so we can make code equivalent to enum as below:
`#define janueary 0
    #define february 1
    #define march 2
    #define april 3
    #define may 4
 
    int aMonth;
    aMonth = janueary;`
In this code aMonth is self-documentation of its intent like enum variable.
But enum save me from type macro for each identifires. Am i right?
Is that the benefit of enum?

Comment: How many different variables do you think you can name `aMonth`?

Comment: You didn't answer my question and also I can't understand your last question?

Comment: It was a rhetorical question. You can't rely on the name of the variable to explain what it contains because when you have lots of different variables with type `enum month`, it's hard to name them all something like `aMonth`. Putting the information in the type name makes it clear for all the variables. And like I said in my answer, it also allows the compiler to produce useful warnings.